# If else if statement in libre office

Tags: if-statement, libreoffice

I am using libre office and I am trying to apply If else if statement but I couldn't do that.

I have numbers with multiple conditions. In column "E" I have numbers. I want separate messages for separate numbers

```
For number-  0.00 = "standard 5,60 Euro charge"
For number-  5,60 = "standard 5,60 Euro charge"
For number-  8,00 = "standard 5,60 Euro charge"
For number- 10,95 = "Standard 14,95 Euro charge" 
For number- 24,95 = "express 29,95 Euro charge"
for number- 30,00 = "Super 45,00 Euro charge"
=IF(E3<="8";"standardpaket 5,6 euro netto" ;elseif(E3="10.95";"DHL Sperrgut 14,95 Euro netto";elseif(E3="24.95";"DHL Express 29,95 Euro netto";else;"Free")))
```

I have tried with this but it doesn't work. I want messages in column "H".

Comment: As this is your first post, please check the formatting of your message.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation for the IF() function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions#IF)? There's no "elseif". Just replace it by a new `IF()` clause. This is quite cumbersome with more than two IF clauses, so you may choose a different solution like a lookup table and [VLOOKUP()](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP)...

Comment: fred If you know answer then pls write here

Answer (score 0):

I think it's been a long time, but since there's no conclusive answer I'll post an answer.

The VLOOKUP() solution is good if you need to choose between ranges.
For fixed values use a custom function.

`Function SEL(byVall as String) as String
    Select Case byVall
        Case 0     : SEL = "standard 5,60 Euro charge"
        Case 5.6   : SEL = "standard 5,60 Euro charge"
        Case 8     : SEL = "standard 5,60 Euro charge"
        Case 10.95 : SEL = "standard 14,95 Euro charge"
        Case 24.95 : SEL = "Express 29,95 Euro charge"
        Case 30    : SEL = "Super 45,00 Euro charge"
        Case Else  : SEL = "Free"
    End Select
End Function`